# How to fix "Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null" in angular firebase project

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to get the firebase token from my authService to the interceptor of my angular 5 project : when the user authentified for the first time, i can get the token id without problem but once i refresh the page (recall the API) i have this error message :
Cannot read property 'getIdToken' of null
    at AuthService.push../src/app/core/auth.service.ts.AuthService.getUserIdToken (auth.service.ts:144)
    at TokenInterceptor.push../src/app/core/token.interceptor.ts.TokenInterceptor.intercept (token.interceptor.ts:31)

my function getToken in authService :

```
getUserIdToken(): Observable<string> {
  return fromPromise ( this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.getIdToken() );
}
```

my interceptor code :
    intercept(request: HttpRequest, next: HttpHandler): Observable> {

```
    if (request.url.indexOf('oauthCallback') > -1) {
        return next.handle(request);
    }

    this.auth = this.inj.get(AuthService); // inject the authservice manually (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18224)
    return this.auth.getUserIdToken().pipe(
        switchMap(token => {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });

            return next.handle(request);
        })
    );
}
```

Thank you for your help.